# AngularJS Controller Rule of Thumb: Treat $scope as write only

Tags: angularjs

I've seen as a best practice that template should treat $scope as read-only and controllers should treat them as write only. I'm guilty of the following practice (due to its simplicity), and what would be the best practice alternative to the following?

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('MainController', function ($scope) {
    var vm = {}; 
    $scope.vm = vm;
  
    vm.setItem = function (item) {
      // Is reading vm data here considered bad? What is better way?
      if (vm.selectedItem === item) {
        vm.message = 'Please select a different item';
        return;
      }
      
      vm.message = 'You selected: ' + item.id;
      vm.selectedItem = item;
    };
    
    activate();
  
    function activate() {
      var items = [];
      for (var i = 1; i <= 15; ++i) {
        items.push({id: i, display: 'Item ' + i});
      }
      vm.items = items;
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainController">
  <h3>{{vm.message}}</h3>
  <div ng-repeat="item in vm.items">
    <a href="#" ng-click="vm.setItem(item)">{{item.display}}</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is a very naive example, but I feel like the need to read scope data in this fashion rears its head a lot, and where should this live? Is the above an accepted pattern?

I know that `selectedItem` can be passed as a second parameter to the `setItem` method, but this seems worse that the view would now have some internal knowledge as to the workings of the controller logic (i.e. setting selectedItem through setItem).

Comment: Shouldn't this be at Code Review?

Comment: @MarcoAurélioDeleu: no, because this is a hypothetical example, not code from a real project.